# Excel Formula required to get the top cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a bandwidth tracker. I want the date to populate of next available in the `Column C`.
For example Name E is getting available on `9/18/2021`. I want this date to populate in cell `C6`.
Can any one tell me the formula to be used for this.

***Bandwidth Tracker:***
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX/MATCH` should work for you. Put below formula `C2` cell and drag down till need.

```
=INDEX($D$1:$I$1,MATCH("Available",D2:I2,0))
```

[image]